# When to use new when declaring a struct

Tags: c++

When do you use `new` with declaring a struct in c++? These links do not use `new`: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/structures/ http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_data_structures.htm

Also this link is similar to my question, but doesn't answer why the segmentation fault:
[when to use new in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217944/when-to-use-new-in-c)

```
struct Node {
  int data;
  struct Node *next;
}
```

---

```
//Add node to end of singly linked list
Node* Insert(Node *head,int data)
{
  //create node
  Node *temp = new Node;     //  *why not:   Node *temp;  :Causes segfault*
  temp->data = data;
  temp->next = '\0';
  //check for empty linked list
  if(head == '\0') {
      head = temp;
  }
  //add to end
  else {
      Node *curr = head;
      while(curr->next != '\0') {
          curr = curr->next;
      }
      curr->next = temp;
  }
  return head;
```

}

Comment: "These links" do not use `Node*`, but `Node`. And that's a huge difference.

Comment: Because `temp` is a pointer to a `Node`. It needs to have a value assigned to it before it can be read, and that value needs to be the address of a proper `Node` object.

Comment: In general, use dynamic memory allocation (via `new`), when the quantity is unknown at compile-time.  Also use dynamic memory allocation when the is too large to be declared as a `static` or global variable.

Answer (score 3):

You use `new` whenever you need to allocate memory (usually on the heap) for your data structure. Now regarding the segfault: if you keep only the line

```
Node *temp; // no more = new Node; here
```

you then try to access the memory it points to further down the line

```
temp->data = data;
temp->next = '\0';
```

but there is no memory allocated, so you will write to some junk memory address that happened to be stored in `temp`. You have to remember that `Node* temp;` just declares the pointer to struct, it **does not initialize it nor allocates memory for it**.

In your situation you may think that `Node data;` will do instead. However, the problem with this is that the object `data` is now stored most likely on the stack, and it will be released at function exit, so you'll end up with dangling pointers. That's why you need to use `new`, since dynamically allocated objects are not bounded to local scope.